# How to subtract one table sum from other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `Issue` and `Return`. Both tables have columns `article_id`, `person_id` and `quantity`. I need to subtract `Return` table from `Issue` table for one person and group the result by article name.

First select looks like this:

```
SELECT Article.Name, SUM(Issue.Quantity)
FROM Issue LEFT JOIN Article ON (Issue.ArticleID = Article.ID)
WHERE Issue.PersonID = 2
GROUP BY Article.Name
```

> ```
> ArticleName  |  Quantity
> ------------------------
> Shoes        |  5
> Coats        |  3
> Hats         |  3
> ```

Second like this:

```
SELECT Article.Name, SUM(Return.Quantity)
FROM Return LEFT JOIN Article ON (Return.ArticleID = Article.ID)
WHERE Return.PersonID = 2
GROUP BY Article.Name
```

> ```
> ArticleName  |  Quantity
> ------------------------
> Shoes        |  3
> Coats        |  2
> Hats         |  0
> ```

Question is, how do I subtract second select from the first (`Return` - `Issue`) to get a table like this:

> ```
> ArticleName  |  Quantity
> ------------------------
> Shoes        |  2
> Coats        |  1
> Hats         |  3
> ```

The Quantity in the final result should be the number of remaining articles to be returned.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a left join rather than inner join in each query? Shouldn't the list be all articles and then the sum(return) - sum(issue)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may work:

(heavily edited - my first answer did not have a chance of working...)

```
SELECT Article.Name
, (SELECT SUM(Issue.Quantity) FROM Issue WHERE Issue.ArticleID = Article.ID AND Issue.PersonID = 2)
- (SELECT SUM(Return.Quantity) FROM Return WHERE Return.ArticleID = Article.ID AND Return.PersonID = 2)
FROM Article
```

Comment: Might want to change that to `SUM(COALESCE(Issue.Quantity,0)) -SUM(COALESCE(Return.Quantity,0))`

Comment: came here to suggest what Conrad did.  For sure check for null values.

Comment: @JiKra Did you try the version after the edit? The first one was certain to return invalid results under almost all circumstances.

Comment: Great, the second edit works perfectly, I will just add that COALESCE function. Thx gratefully. :-)